# Closure Compiler: force 100% type coverage

Tags: google-closure-compiler

When I run the closure compiler to type-check my code, it shows me the type coverage (but only when there's an error), e.g.:

```
1 error(s), 0 warning(s), 90.8% typed
```

Is there a flag to enforce that all code be typed?

(Addendum: Is there a way to see type coverage when there are no errors?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be well documented, but `reportUnknownTypes` is listed here:
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Flags-and-Options

Enabling this diagnostic groups should report places where the "unknown" type needed to be used.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much what I wanted. I's a bit cumbersome... it's a bit over-eager on throwing on all sorts of lambdas, try/catch errors, etc. But it helped me found a few places that really did need type annotations.